# When will the Naruto: Shippuden English dubbed version resume production?

Tags: naruto

My question is, when will the English dubbed versions of *Naruto: Shippuden* episodes 313 through 432 be released, and where will they be available to watch? I love the series, and cannot wait to finish!

Comment: That's a ***lot*** of episodes...so I would genuinely imagine there's going to be a wait.

Comment: From what I understand they are dubbing one ep. a month so around the end of the month there should be ep 313 and next month 314 so on.

Comment: Even if they are released eventually, I couldn't imagine watching them. After the show went off the air, I started watching the subtitled episodes online, and am so far ahead in the story now, watching new dubbed episodes would be a huge leap backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question. I was wondering the same thing for a long time. I searched on Wikipedia for the [list of *Shippuden* episodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes#Season_14:_2013) and saw that all episodes after Episode 312 are to be released on January 26, 2016 on DVD, which will eventually go online. Still, I love the series, too. I've been a fan of the original since I was a kid and Shippuden is great. I only watch it in English dub, but your guess is as good as mine when they'll come out on a good site. Possibly because the new episodes still need to be voiced.

Comment: Maybe you should add the Wikipedia link, just for quick reference

Comment: Thank you for your response and the recommendation. I'll stay on top of that website. I've recently been watching all of the naruto movies, they too are great, but it only makes me want to see how the series continues. Thanks again:)